# Stop reading bytes from serial port (Python/RPi/UART)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, communication, pyserial

This problem is quite complicated. Seemingly I have simple two-way communication beetwen 2 devices where reading side is Raspberry pi 3. I'm trying to transfer file. I'm sending it part by part (5kb part). It looks like:

1) Sending side send first 5kb part (exactly 5136 bytes where first 16 bytes are ID/SIZE/ADD_INFO/CRC)

2) RPi3 read 5136 bytes, and calculate CRC for chunk.

3) RPi3 compare CRC received from sending side and calculated by RPi

4a) If CRC doesn't match I switch lanes from RX to TX line using Dual Bus Buffer Gate With 3-State Outputs and set High State at TX line (I keep it for 30ms).

4b) If CRC match I just wait for next chunk of file

5) Sending side switch lanes too and read my TX state if state is HIGH/1 (when CRC doesn't match) it sends same chunk (retransmission) if state is LOW/0 sends another chunk. (changing state take 10 ms)

On osciloscope it looks like this (4a):

[image: 4a]

and this (4b):

[image: 4b]

Beetwen 5136 chunk there is free time to calculate CRC then we have on RPi3 side changing state if we have to because CRC doesn't match (red lines at 4a) and reading TX side from Sending side.

Ok now some simplified code from RPi:

```
def recv():
    while True:
        #Set line to low because I want to read data
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)
        ID = ser.read(4)
        SIZE = ser.read(4)
        ADD_INFO = ser.read(4)
        CRC = ser.read(4)
        #get crc from sending side
        crc_chunk = int.from_bytes(CRC, byteorder='little')
        data = ser.read(5120)
        #calculating CRC from chunk
        rpiCRC = crcSTM(data)

        while True:
             <--- here I wait about 20ms to calculate CRC
            if rpiCRC != crc_chunk:
                #Crc doesn't match I want retransmission
                GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
                <--- keep it HIGH for about 30ms
                break

            else:
                #keep it low because crc match and we are waiting for next chunk
                GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
                break
```

All this looks legit but to the point. I always get only first chunk after that RPi just stop reading bytes. It only happen in case '4b' I get first chunk properly and I'm waiting for next one and then RPi just stop reading bytes or give me just some scratches from time to time. I test what If i get first chunk properly and set retransmission thing but everything looks great and I was getting all the time retransmission of first chunk and get it all the time. I came to this that changing line on sending side when I have LOW/1 state affects on RPi and it just stop reading bytes properly. Don't know why it's messing it and don't know how to fight it. I tryied  flushing buffer, closing port before sending side chaning line and open it after it changes line again but all this just do nothing what can I do more ?

P.S This waiting things i do in my own timer but there is no need to put here code like code from sending side because problem is on RPi side. 
P.S sorry for chaotic language but I was trying do explane it as simply as i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fight it. I have enabled option "Would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial" in `sudo raspi-congif`. Don't know why this was messing everything but disabling this fix it. This is quite strange because I'm playing with raspberry and serial some time and there was no problem if RPi3 was sending something via uart or when it was just reading without changing lines etc :)